# how to integrate Vue Apollo in Vue Vite project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-apollo

I'm trying to integrate Vue Apollo in a a Vite project using the composition API.
My main.js file look like this:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import * as apolloProvider from '../apollo.provider'
import router from './router'


const app = createApp(App)

app
.use(router)
.use(apolloProvider.provider)
.mount('#app')
```

In the vue4 setup section is written to update the main.js in this way:

```js
import { createApp, provide, h } from 'vue'
import { DefaultApolloClient } from '@vue/apollo-composable'

const app = createApp({
  setup () {
    provide(DefaultApolloClient, apolloClient)
  },

  render: () => h(App),
})
```

Can anyone help me to integrate this code into my main.js?
I've tryied to do that but as soon as I import **DefaultApolloClient**, my app goes in loop refreshing itself.
How can I solve this problem?

p.s.
here my packages.json content:

```json
{
  "name": "kiddo-vite-frontend",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vue/apollo-composable": "^4.0.0-alpha.17",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.9",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.6",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.10",
    "apollo-link": "^1.2.14",
    "apollo-link-context": "^1.0.20",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.17",
    "graphql": "^16.5.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
    "vue": "^3.2.30",
    "vue-apollo": "^3.1.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^2.3.3",
    "vite": "^2.9.9"
  }
}
```

Thank you

Valerio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That loop happens if you start the dev server without having installed the [prerequisite dependencies](https://v4.apollo.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html). Follow the steps below to resolve the issue.

### Getting Started with `@vue/apollo-composable` and Vue 3

1. Install the prerequisites along with `@vue/apollo-composable`:

   ```sh
   $ npm install --save graphql graphql-tag @apollo/client
   $ npm install --save @vue/apollo-composable
   ```
2. In `main.js`, add the following boilerplate to initialize your Apollo client to [GraphQLZero](https://graphqlzero.almansi.me) (a fake online GraphQL API):

   ```js
    import { createApp } from 'vue'
    import { DefaultApolloClient } from '@vue/apollo-composable'
    import { ApolloClient, createHttpLink, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client/core'
    import App from './App.vue'

    const httpLink = createHttpLink({
      uri: 'https://graphqlzero.almansi.me/api',
    })
    const cache = new InMemoryCache()
    const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
      link: httpLink,
      cache,
    })

    createApp(App)
      .provide(DefaultApolloClient, apolloClient)
      .mount('#app')
   ```
3. Create a component that uses `useQuery` from `@vue/apollo-composable`:

   ```html
    <script setup>
    import { useQuery } from '@vue/apollo-composable'
    import gql from 'graphql-tag'

    const { result } = useQuery(gql`
      query getUser {
        user(id: 1) {
          id
          name
        }
      }
    `)
    </script>

    <template>
      <h2>Hello {{ result?.user?.name ?? 'world' }}</h2>
    </template>
   ```
4. Start the dev server:

   ```sh
   $ npm run dev
   ```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-apollo-composable?file=src%2Fmain.js)